# Codeigniter scripts loading twice/not being removed with partial views

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

So, I load partial views inside the "main" view, and put the content inside a div, like this:

```
<div class="page-content" id="inside_page"></div>

<script>
            $("#myTab").click(function() {
                location.hash="myTab";
                App.blockUI({
                    boxed: !0
                });
                $.ajax({ 
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>"+"index.php/welcome/myTabContent", 
                    data: {},
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.status == 2) {
                            window.location = "/";
                        }else{
                            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                            App.unblockUI();
                            $("#inside_page").empty();
                            $("#inside_page").html(data);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                        App.unblockUI();
                        bootbox.alert("<p>Error</p>");
                    }
                });     
            });
</script>
```

The partial view includes  tags, and when I change tabs, or load the tab again, scripts that have been already loaded, will not be removed and will keep running until the user reloads the page. How can I stop that from happening?